# Calculate percentage of positioned elements for parallax opacity

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

I'm trying to calculate a percent number (0.0 - 2.0/0% - 200%) so that I can change the opacity of a div as it comes in and out of view.

- When the window is above the viewable area, the percent is at or less than 0
- When the window is at the exact center of the viewable area, the percent is 1.0
- And when the window is below the viewable area, the percent is 2.0 and up

And while scrolling in and out of view, it would be a portion thereof.

Somehow I need compare the window's vertical center to the area's vertical center, but I'm having a hard time getting the calculations right.

So far I have

```
var p = {
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop(),
    documentHeight: $(document).height(),
    windowHeight: $(window).height(),
    contentTop: $('.content').position().top,
    contentHeight: $('.content').height()
};

if (p.windowHeight / 2 + p.scrollTop < p.contentHeight / 2 + p.contentTop) {

    p.percent = (p.windowHeight / 2 + p.scrollTop) / (p.contentHeight / 2 + p.contentTop);
}
else if (p.windowHeight / 2 + p.scrollTop > p.contentHeight / 2 + p.contentTop) {

    p.percent =  (p.windowHeight / 2 + p.scrollTop) / (p.contentHeight / 2 + p.documentHeight - p.contentHeight - p.contentTop);
}
else p.percent = 1;

$('.content').animate({
    opacity: 1 - Math.abs(p.percent - 1)
}, 1);
```

But I'm not factoring in the document height, so I know I'm missing something.  I also feel this could be done in one equation, without the if/else

Here's a non-functioning fiddle I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/nxdTn/

---

To better demonstrate, see below examples.

Yellow is the document, the transparant grey is the window, and the blue is the viewable area.

Blue would be at 0 opacity:
[image]

At 100% opacity:
[image]

And back to 0:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's many ways to skin a cat, but personally I would try to determine some bounds on what the values for `scrollTop` will be when `content` enters and exits the window and then just calculate `scrollTop`'s position in relation to those bounds. No center points or document's height needed.

One minor change I had to make to your CSS was to remove the margin from `content` and add it as padding to `body`. The margin was treating `content` as if it's `position.top()` value was 0.

```
var p = {
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop(),
    windowHeight: $(window).height(),
    contentTop: $('.content').position().top,
    contentHeight: $('.content').height()
};

// determine scrollTop's bounds where content enters & exits the window
p.lowerBound = p.contentTop - p.windowHeight;
p.upperBound = p.contentTop + p.contentHeight;

// determine scrollTop's position percentage (x2) in relation to bounds
p.percent = (p.scrollTop - p.lowerBound) / (p.upperBound - p.lowerBound) * 2;
```

You can see a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/nxdTn/3/

Hope it's what you're looking for.